# Loop through cfhttp filecontent

Tags: coldfusion

I need to manipulate each line of a cfhttp.filecontent I got from a get:

```
<cfhttp url="www.internet.com/file.html" method="GET" resolveurl="false"></cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
    #cfhttp.FileContent#
</cfoutput>
```

How would I loop through cfhttp.filecontent line by line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you can use list functions with some combination of chr(10) and/or chr(13) as the list delimiter. But it all depends on how "lines" are defined in your content.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list="#cfhttp.FileContent#" delimiters="#chr(10)#" index="line">
    #line#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you're using ColdFusion 9) is to write the content of the `CFHTTP` request to a file on disk, and then use the [`file` attribute of `cfloop`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_15.html) to loop over the file line by line.